# How to fix 'adc is null' error after updating 'adc=addtocart' in Selenium WebDriver Page Factory?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-factory

[I am using selenium where I'm implementing page factory getting this error[using addtocart test where I'm calling methods from addtocart class it's showing error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR3kq.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1MBd.jpg)

I tried to do the above, but i was getting this adc is null but I changed adc=addtocartinside a setup to this above one,   now I'm getting this. Trying
I'm creating test cases in nopcommerce.demo